# HTML JQuery Image Slider

Tags: jquery, html

I am having trouble with this [image slider.](http://responsiveslides.com/) The images are supposed to fade in and out, each image being displayed for 5 seconds. I am relatively new to coding and this site and was wondering if anyone would help me with this problem.

At the moment I am just stuck on the first image, and the slideshow is not working at all.

I know you haven't got access to the ResponsiveSlides.js file but I believe that there is a small error that is not within that js file, but within my beginner code.

Here is the CSS and part of the HTML:

```css
.rslides {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  }

.rslides li {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  }

.rslides li:first-child {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  }

.rslides img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  }
```

```html
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/responsiveslides.min.js"></script>
  <title>George Burke</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styling.css"/>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
       $(document).on("scroll", function(){
        if ($(document).scrollTop() > 100) {
          $(".header").addClass("shrink");
        } else {
          $(".header").removeClass("shrink");
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(function(){
  // Trigger maximage
  jQuery('#maximage').maximage();
});


  </script>
  <script>
    $(function () {
      $("#.rslides").responsiveSlides({
        auto: true,
        fade: 500,
        speed: 100,
      });

    });
  </script>

 </head>

 <body>

    <div id="maximage">
      <ul class="rslides">
      <li><img src="images/turbines.jpg" alt=""></li>
      <li><img src="images/london.jpg" alt=""></li>
      <li><img src="images/nbauk.jpg" alt=""></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <header class="header">
    <nav>
   <h1>George Burke</h1>
<!--
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">me</a></li>  
      <li><a href="">photos</a></li>
      <li><a href="">queries</a></li>
      <li><a href="">connect</a></li>
    </ul>
-->
```

Comment: Did you look for JavaScript error in the Debug Console of your browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in the code:

```
$("#.rslides")
```

should be

```
$(".rslides")
```

it refers to

```
<ul class="rslides">
```

`.` is the selector for a `class` while `#` is the selector for an `id`
`.` and `#` cannot be used simultaneously as `#.`.